# - symbol in the url gives error in Firefox and urllib.request

Tags: python, firefox, web, urllib2, urllib

some-.site.com gives error when opening from Firefox or Python urllib.request but works in Chrome.
What can be the problem?

Output in firefox:

```
Server not found
```

In Python:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1251, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Comment: Where in the URL is the - symbol? Give an example of the URL's you are trying to open.

Comment: any url wirh xxx-.xx.xx gives error.

Comment: Where does Chrome actually take you? That's not a valid DNS hostname.

Comment: RFC3986 says its valid as a URL, but RFC1035 says the hyphen can only be used as an "interior" character (first and last must be letter or digit) in a DNS name.

Comment: I'm curious what `socket.gethostbyname('some-.site.com')` does.